# Can Webdriver run at the speed of Selenium IDE?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm working with a custom test runner to execute Selenium tests within TeamCity. The latest feature of this is the ability to create tests in the IDE and saving them in html which the test runner will then run in Python.

The immediate difference when comparing the Python tests to the IDE tests is the execution speed of the IDE at it's fastest. I understand that the `set_speed()` function I have seen in Selenium was deprecated from WebDriver some time ago but is there a way to run WebDriver tests quicker?

The main drawback as more tests are added will be the execution time (obviously) so it'd be great to speed things up where possible.

And some code for the test runner...

```
class BPTSeleniumTestCase(test.TransactionTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox() # can you set speed here somehow?
        super(BPTSeleniumTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    def setUp(self):
        self.live_server_url = settings.BASE_URL
        self.driver.live_server_url = self.live_server_url
        self.wait = Wait(self.driver)
```

Comment: The simple answer is no. But i could be mistaken, pretty sure this time, i am not.

Comment: @aimbire, I too, believe you are correct.

Comment: Yeah, thanks guys. I feared this was the case :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no settings available to speed up the WebDriver execution. WebDriver execution speed also vary depending on the browser drivers used and the programming languages. I tried to explore the FireFoxDriver profile settings to improve execution speed, there were no settings available for this.